# ORA-01006: Bind Variable while Executing Select

Tags: oracle, plsql

During the Initialization block of a newly created package, I populate one field in a record stored in an associative array (Indexed by VARCHAR2).  I then loop over the associative array to store the second field on each record.   These records store a Table Name and the column name which the foreign key for a given table.  (Our product has a generic form so I can later generate some SQL with the only difference being the table and column names).  Here is some example code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pk_example IS
  TYPE pkt_TableInfo IS RECORD
  (
    BaseTable VARCHAR2(30),
    FKColumn VARCHAR2(30)
  );
  TYPE pkt_TableInfoTable IS TABLE OF pkt_TableInfo INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
  pk_tTableInfo pkt_TableInfoTable;
  pk_sIndex VARCHAR2(30);

/***FUNCTION AND PROCEDURE DEFINITIONS***/

--Initialization Section
BEGIN
  pk_tTableInfo('TABLE_A').BaseTable := 'TABLE_B';
  pk_tTableInfo('TABLE_C').BaseTable := 'TABLE_D';

  pk_sIndex := pk_tTableInfo.FIRST;
  WHILE pk_sIndex IS NOT NULL LOOP
    SELECT acc.column_name
    INTO pk_tTableInfo(pk_sIndex).FKColumn
    FROM all_constraints ac
    INNER JOIN all_constraints ac2 ON ac.r_owner = ac2.owner AND ac.r_constraint_name = ac2.constraint_name
    INNER JOIN all_cons_columns acc ON ac.owner = acc.owner AND ac.constraint_name = acc.constraint_name
    WHERE ac.owner = sys_context('userenv', 'current_schema')
    AND ac.constraint_type = 'R'
    AND ac.table_name = pk_sIndex
    AND ac2.table_name = pk_tTableInfo(pk_sIndex).BaseTable;

    pk_sIndex := pk_tTableInfo.NEXT(pk_sIndex);
  END LOOP;
END pk_example;
```

Everything compiles just fine, however, whenever I attempt to run a function from this package, I receive an "ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist" error pointing to the line "SELECT acc.column_name".

Now for the kicker.  This works in my development environment but is failing when I try to run the package in QA.

- I have all the same permissions and I can run the query just fine.  In fact, if I replace pk_tTableInfo(pk_sIndex) with a string 'TABLE_B' the query runs just fine. (For the first pass through the loop...then I get No Data)
- The foreign keys are the same between environments.
- Both environments are running Oracle 12cR2.

Thank you for taking the time to read through this, I appreciate any input.

Comment: In 12CR2, column name can be more than 30 characters long. Redefine your type with FKcolumn number(128)

Comment: @Tejash: While our application runs on 12c, it was originally developed on a much earlier version of Oracle so all table and column names still adhere to the 30 character limit.  However, not wanting to ignore the only comment on my question, I gave it a try and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've just bumped into the quite same issue. I have `FOR..LOOP` cursor and I'm getting `ORA-01006` error on `FOR` line. Query is not dynamic. It was working perfectly on Oracle 11g but we upgraded Oracle to 19c version and this issue occured.
The only suspicious thing was that query used function in `WHERE` clause. Luckily it didn't reference any columns so I removed it from query and calculated before `FOR..LOOP` statement into a variable. After that it worked like magic.

In your case I would try to get rid of references to collection and use just scalar variables and then assign them to collection elements. The same goes for `pk_tTableInfo(pk_sIndex).BaseTable` value.